# Визуализация связей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста как реализовать визуализацию связей между блоками(таблицами) на javascript. Т.е. я дропнул на холст элементы и хочу отображалась связь. Так реализовано, например, в `phpmyadmin` при просмотре связей таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

> холст

Вероятно `canvas`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  // Рисуем Ваши блоки по каким-либо координатам
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 30);
  ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 30);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  // x - ширина первого блока + его отступ по X
  // y - отступ первого блока по Y + эстетический отступ в 4
  ctx.moveTo(60, 14);
  // Прибавляем отступ по x, чтобы сделать "ножку" в 10
  ctx.lineTo(70, 14);
  // x - ширина второго блока + его отступ по X + "ножка" в 10
  // y - отступ по Y + эстетический отступ в 4
  ctx.lineTo(160, 104);
  // Убираем ножку в сам блок
  ctx.lineTo(150, 104);
  
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#0f0';
  // Рисуем
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

```css
canvas{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(100,100,100,.3);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```